# LTE: Set up response

Tags: installation, procedure, lte

I have seen that in Setup Request procedure in LTE

the response message contains

served plmnids, 
served group ids ,
and served mme codes

So it means a mme can serve multiple plmns , multiple mme groups,

but  what is meaning of sending list of mme codes , because a mme is identified by group id and mme code .So ideally there should be only one mme code with which we can identify this particular mme which is responding .

So why we have multiple mme codes in response message ?

I am referring  S1 Application Protocol (S1AP)
(3GPP TS 36.413 version 10.9.0 Release 10).

Thanks,

SDK

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the [S1-Flex](https://www.nttdocomo.co.jp/english/binary/pdf/corporate/technology/rd/technical_journal/bn/vol13_1/vol13_1_033en.pdf) feature.

If the UE has a temporary identity, this will sent to the ENB during the RRC establishment phase.

The ENB will use the MME code present in this identity to select the MME (assuming multiple MME are connected to the same ENB) where to send the S1AP InitialUeMessage.

The point of having multiple MME identities in the same MME instance is to handle failover/loadbalancing/maintenance operations.

GUMMEIs can be moved at runtime (MME configuration update) between different MMEs in the MME pool according to the requirements.

Comment: setup response is sent from MME to Enb , So if the response contains multiple MME Codes how enb will identify , the particaular MME which have replied to this request ?

Comment: Simply by looking at the SCTP connection from where the S1SetupResponse is coming from. All the GUMMEIs listed in the S1SetupRespponse are supported by the MME on that particular SCTP connection. If the ENB is simultaneously connected to different MMEs, the supported GUMMEIs, RelativeMMECapacity and (if provided) UE temporary identity has to be evaluated to select the correct SCTP connection/MME where to send the InitialUeMessage.